# How to enable USB debugging in LineageOS 14 on Moto G2014?

Tags: usb-debugging, lineageos, developer-options

I want to build LineageOS 15 from source following [the titan image build guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/titan/build) which requires the transfer of vendor specific files and thus an `adb` connection after enabling USB debugging.

I didn't find a LineageOS-specific guide on turning development tools including USB debugging on, so I went with my Android knowledge of tapping 6 times on the build number in the phone settings. This shows a screen with my home screen background and the LineageOS emblem. The emblem responds to taps anywhere on the screen by changing it's styling, but nothing else. I can go back and use the phone including repeating the journey to the emblem screen.

I get that these settings should be hidden for non-dev users and don't need to be reachable very intuitively, but that's covered by hiding the function behind the 6 taps on the version item. After that the proceedure to enable development features can be intuitive again.

Comment: Just a side note on building (which is off-topic on this site, so not included in answer): don't follow the official guide on vendor blobs, instead add [TheMuppets](https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_motorola) to your local manifest for known-good extracted blobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I went with my Android knowledge of tapping 6 times on the build number in the phone settings. This shows a screen with my home screen background and the LineageOS emblem.

Despite what you claimed, you've tapped the wrong place. Tapping "Android version" will show a big N; tapping "LineageOS version" will show you the LOS logo; tapping the actual "Build number" item, which is the second-to-last item in the About phone menu, is what you should go for.

On top of that, it should be tapped **7** times, and each tap should notify you about needing more taps to unlock Dev Options.

Answer (score 0):

I tapped something else than the build number. There's a lot of room for improvement here, unfortunately, LineageOS developers don't care about suggestions of improvements in their issue tracker.

Comment: It's unreasonable to blame LOS for misreading / mistake on your part, unless it's because you're not using English and got mislead by translation.

Comment: The showed logo made me think which is always a bug. I can't discuss this with the LineageOS devs because they refuse input on this because of the automation of their issue tracker. It's reasonable to complain about this - especially if I accept the outcome of this discussion or its postponing no question asked.

Comment: The GitLab issue tracker is just that, a serious place for discussing issues, *with concrete proof* (usually logcat). For lighter discussion you should've used their [official subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/) instead, which is way more open. Maybe also offer video proof on where you tapped and what popped out, because I had/have *dozens* of LOS devices and I know well how it works.